# How can I calculate the curl of this vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, spherical-coordinates, curl

I have a vector field which is originallly written as $$ \mathbf A = \frac{\mu_0~n~I}{2} ~\hat \theta$$ and I translated it like this $$\mathbf A = 0 ~\hat{r},~~ \frac{\mu_0 ~n~I~r}{2} ~\hat{\theta} , ~~0 ~\hat{\phi}$$
($r$ is the distance from origin, $\theta$ is azimuthal angle and $\phi$ is the polar angle).

I want to calculate its divergence, so I have two options either change it into Cartesian system and then take the curl or take the curl in spherical coordinates. Let’s take the curl in spherical coordinates:

$$(curl~\mathbf A)_r = \frac{1}{r\sin \theta} \frac{\partial (A_{\phi} \sin \theta)}{\theta} -\frac{1}{r\sin \theta} \frac{\partial A_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}$$ I really don't know what is $r$ and that $\sin \theta$ which appearing in the first term above, nevertheless, it is zero as $A_{\phi}$ is zero and even our $A_\theta$ is independent of $\theta$, therefore, whole term above is zero. So, we have $(curl~\mathbf A)_r = 0$.

We have $$(curl~\mathbf A)_{\theta} = \frac{1}{r\sin \theta} \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \phi} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial ( r A_{\phi} )}{\partial r}$$ I want to repeat that I don't know if those $r$ and $\sin \theta$ are part of my vector field or not, nonetheless, both terms will be zero because $A_r$ and $A_{\phi}$ are zero. Therefore, $(curl~\mathbf A)_{\theta} = 0$.

The last component,  $$(curl~\mathbf A)_{\phi}=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial (rA_{\theta})}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta}$$ I'm just assuming that $r$ which appears in the formula above is same as the one which appears in my vector field.
$$(curl~\mathbf A)_{\phi}= \frac{\mu_0 ~n~I}{2r} \frac{\partial r^2}{\partial r}$$ $$ (curl~\mathbf A)_{\phi} = \mu_0~n~I $$ Now, I want to know if I'm correct.

How can convert the above result into cartesian system? Well, I have something like this (if we call curl of $\mathbf A$ as $\mathbf B$ ) $$ \mathbf B( r, \theta, \phi) = \left( 0, 0 , \mu_0 ~n~I \right)$$ we don't have $\phi$ as an angle and all three $x, ~y, ~z$ involve either $sine$ or $cosine$ of $\phi$ and multiplication by $r$ as $$ x=r\sin\phi \cos\theta\\ \hspace{10px} y=r\sin\phi \sin\theta \\ z =r\cos\phi$$ so, in that sense all the cartesian components are zero because $r$ is zero.

Please guide me through it.

Comment: I am unsure. What exactly does $\mathbf A = 0 ~\hat{r},~~ \frac{\mu_0 ~n~I~r}{2} ~\hat{\theta} , ~~0 ~\hat{\phi}$ mean? I assume that $\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi}$ are "basis vectors" for $r,\theta,\phi$ and that the expression in the question is something like $$ \mathbf{A}=\left(\vphantom{\frac I2}\right.\overset{\substack{r\text{ component}\\\downarrow}}{\vphantom{\frac I2}0},\overset{\substack{\theta\text{ component}\\\downarrow}}{\frac{\mu_0nIr}2},\overset{\substack{\phi\text{ component}\\\downarrow}}{\vphantom{\frac I2}0}\left.\vphantom{\frac I2}\right) $$ Is this correct?

Comment: If  this is so, then $A=0$ identically because $r=0$ for all vectors, and the curl of a $0$ vector field is $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Actually, I myslef don’t know what it means when we write $$\mathbf A(\vec r) = \frac{\mu_0~n~I}{2} \hat{\phi}$$. I thought it meant that $\mathbf A$ had only the phi component but now I think it means that $\mathbf A$ points in the phi direction.

Comment: If the quantity after the $\mathbf{A}=$ indicates $A_r=0,A_\theta=\frac{\mu_0nIr}2,A_\phi=0$, then the vector field is a $0$ field because $A_r=0$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes sir I totally agree with that. I want to know what according to you does this notation mean $$\mathbf A (\vec r) = \frac{\mu_0~n~I}{2} \hat{\phi}$$

Comment: I have thought for some time and in my opinion $$\mathbf A = \frac{\mu_0 ~n~I}{2} \hat{\phi}$$ means that the magnitude of $\mathbf A$ is $\frac{\mu_0~n~I}{2}$ but it always points in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction.

Comment: which direction is the $\hat{\phi}$ direction?

Comment: @robjohn Perpendicular to $\hat{r}$ and to z-axis.